# Reading multiple csv file that are located in the same directory in R

Tags: r, read.csv

Hello I am trying to read in multiple csv files that are located in the same directory. I would like to select the working directory and then read in all the files into one big list(if possible). My attempt is below. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated. I do not know what I am doing wrong!

```
directory <- dlgDir()

file_list <- list.files(path = "directory", pattern = "*.csv")

bigList <- sapply(file_list, read.csv)
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Try `lapply` instead of `sapply` because it returns a list. Also use `path = directory` not `path = "directory"`.

Comment: When I use path = directory I received this error Error in list.files(path = directory, pattern = "*.csv") : 
  invalid 'path' argument

Comment: What is the `directory` object? A number? NA? It should be "a character vector of full path names".

Comment: The directory is a path to where the csv files are located

Comment: My question is can I select the directory where the csv files are located. Then use that directory to locate the files and read hose csv files into a list?

Comment: I mean, what do you get when you do `is(directory)`? I'm not having any problems reading in multiple csvs into a list.

Comment: Sorry, I get “nativeGUI” I am guessing that is where the problem is

Comment: You probably also want to include `full.names = TRUE` in your `list.files` function

Comment: How can I change the directory variable to be “a character vector of full path names”?

Comment: I got it thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example using an updated version of Alberto Barradas' [Pokémon Stats](https://www.kaggle.com/abcsds/pokemon) data from kaggle.com that reads the list of files from a directory and combines them into a data frame.

```
download.file("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/lgreski/pokemonData/master/pokemonData.zip",
              "pokemonData.zip",
              method="curl",mode="wb")
unzip("pokemonData.zip")

thePokemonFiles <- list.files("./pokemonData",
                                  full.names=TRUE)
thePokemonFiles 

pokemonData <- lapply(thePokemonFiles,function(x) read.csv(x))
```

At this point, the object `pokemonData` is a list of seven dataframes, containing one of seven generations of Pokémon, which we'll demonstrate with `summary()`.

```
    > summary(pokemonData)
     Length Class      Mode
[1,] 13     data.frame list
[2,] 13     data.frame list
[3,] 13     data.frame list
[4,] 13     data.frame list
[5,] 13     data.frame list
[6,] 13     data.frame list
[7,] 13     data.frame list
```

To combine them into a single data frame, we use `do.call()` with the `rbind()` function.

```
pokemonData <- do.call(rbind,pokemonData)
```

To demonstrate that the `pokemonData` object now consists of a single data frame with all seven generations of Pokémon, we'll execute `summary()` again.

```
> summary(pokemonData)
     Number                             Name    
 Min.   :  1.0   Abra                     :  1  
 1st Qu.:208.0   Aerodactyl               :  1  
 Median :402.0   AerodactylMega Aerodactyl:  1  
 Mean   :405.4   Alakazam                 :  1  
 3rd Qu.:609.0   AlakazamMega Alakazam    :  1  
 Max.   :807.0   Arbok                    :  1  
                 (Other)                  :887  
     Type1         Type2         Total             HP        
 Water  :122          :385   Min.   :175.0   Min.   :  1.00  
 Normal :110   Flying :108   1st Qu.:330.0   1st Qu.: 50.00  
 Grass  : 82   Ground : 37   Median :455.0   Median : 66.00  
 Bug    : 78   Poison : 35   Mean   :437.6   Mean   : 69.44  
 Psychic: 66   Psychic: 35   3rd Qu.:518.0   3rd Qu.: 80.00  
 Fire   : 58   (Other):258   Max.   :780.0   Max.   :255.00  
 (Other):377   NA's   : 35                                   
     Attack          Defense         SpecialAtk   
 Min.   :  5.00   Min.   :  5.00   Min.   : 10.0  
 1st Qu.: 55.00   1st Qu.: 50.00   1st Qu.: 50.0  
 Median : 75.00   Median : 70.00   Median : 65.0  
 Mean   : 79.83   Mean   : 74.39   Mean   : 73.4  
 3rd Qu.:100.00   3rd Qu.: 90.00   3rd Qu.: 95.0  
 Max.   :190.00   Max.   :230.00   Max.   :194.0  

   SpecialDef         Speed          Generation   
 Min.   : 20.00   Min.   :  5.00   Min.   :1.000  
 1st Qu.: 50.00   1st Qu.: 45.00   1st Qu.:2.000  
 Median : 70.00   Median : 65.00   Median :4.000  
 Mean   : 72.37   Mean   : 68.21   Mean   :3.713  
 3rd Qu.: 90.00   3rd Qu.: 90.00   3rd Qu.:5.000  
 Max.   :230.00   Max.   :180.00   Max.   :7.000  

 Legendary  
 False:734  
 True : 65  
 NA's : 94
```